# Saving and reading the last successful execution as a json-file

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, json

I've got some tools that run perdiodically like weekly or monthly that don't support any retry mechanism. In order to increase their chance to succeed in case a database wasn't reachable or some other problem occured, I simply schedule them to run several times per day or a couple of days in month.

Currently they do their job every time they run, regardles whether they succeeded the first time or not. I'd like to change this by saving a simple token with the timestamp of the last successful execution.

---

## Implementation

This is where my `Tick` class comes into play. I designed it handle a json-token with only a single property. I know at this point it could be a plain text file, but this escalates pretty quickly so I'd like it to be future-proof.

```js
{"created_on": "2022-09-01T15:36:08.434008"}
```

It allows me to save the current `datetime` and also takes care of reading it and checking whether the token is still valid or already expired. Its job is simple, but I wanted to have it as pretty and as smartass as it can be. This is how it looks like:

```py
import json
import pathlib
import os
from functools import lru_cache
from datetime import datetime, date
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, Union

class Tick:
    def __init__(self, file_name: Union[str, bytes, os.PathLike], lifetime: float, calc_as: Callable[..., float]):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.lifetime = lifetime
        self.calc_as = calc_as

    def check(self):
        pathlib.Path(os.path.dirname(self.file_name)).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        data = json.dumps({self.created_on.__name__: datetime.now()}, cls=_JsonDateTimeEncoder)
        with open(self.file_name, "w") as f:
            f.write(data)
        self.created_on.cache_clear()

    @lru_cache  # avoid reading the file more than once until updated
    def created_on(self) -> Union[datetime, None]:
        if not os.path.isfile(self.file_name):
            return None

        with open(self.file_name, "r") as f:
            return json.loads(f.read(), cls=_JsonDateTimeDecoder)[self.created_on.__name__]

    def seconds(self) -> Union[float, None]:
        return (datetime.now() - self.created_on()).total_seconds() if self.created_on() else None

    def minutes(self) -> Union[float, None]:
        return self.seconds() / 60 if self.seconds() else None

    def hours(self) -> Union[float, None]:
        return self.minutes() / 60 if self.minutes() else None

    def days(self) -> Union[float, None]:
        return self.hours() / 24 if self.hours() else None

    def is_expired(self) -> bool:
        return not self.calc_as(self) or self.calc_as(self) > self.lifetime

    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        return not self.is_expired()
```

Since the `json` package cannot handle `datetime` by default, I created these two classes to handle that part.

```py
class _JsonDateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(o, (date, datetime)):
            return o.isoformat()


class _JsonDateTimeDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(object_hook=self.parse_datetime_or_default)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_datetime_or_default(d: Dict):
        r = dict()
        for k in d.keys():
            r[k] = d[k]
            if isinstance(d[k], str):
                try:
                    r[k] = datetime.fromisoformat(d[k])  # try parse date-time
                except ValueError:
                    pass  # default value is already set
        return r
```

---

## Example

This is how I test it:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime
from src.tick_off import Tick

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tick = Tick(r"c:\temp\token_test__.json", lifetime=5, calc_as=Tick.hours)

    # tick.check()
    print(tick.hours())
    print("is_expired:", tick.is_expired())
    print("is_valid:", tick.is_valid())
```

---

The one thing that bothers me the most is the repeated conditions in methods like `minutes`, `hours` & `days` that use virtually identical conditions:

> ```
> return self.seconds() / 60 if self.seconds() else None
> ```

Unfortunatelly `None / 60` doesn't produce `None` but an error, but maybe there is some *smart* way one can get rid of these conditions without turning it into a `try/except` that would be even more ugly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the positives: you've put some effort into typehints, caching, and encapsulation, all good things. You've started into `pathlib` support, which is good, and you target Python 3, which is good.

`Union[datetime, None]` is just `Optional[datetime]`.

`file_name` is too broad in its type. Just force the caller to pass a `Path`. This is not an external-facing library: you don't need to, and should not, adopt the shotgun approach to argument types. After all of that effort, you still don't use `Path` properly - you're calling top-level `open()` and `os.path.isfile` when you should be using the `Path` equivalents.

When you write

```
pathlib.Path(self.file_name).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

It seems to me like this should be getting `.parent`, not making a directory named the same as the target file.

`calc_as` is a fascinating, convoluted mistake. Don't do any of this. Just accept a `timedelta` for `lifetime` instead of a `float`. Delete all of your time unit conversion functions.

Don't `dumps` and `loads` string-based functions; call their file alternatives `dump` and `load`.

`is_expired` etc. are good candidates for being made `@property`s.

If you want to support `datetime` parsing in JSON, fine. Your implementation, first, is more complicated than it needs to be: don't subclass `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder`; just pass function references to `object_hook` and `default` at time of serialisation. Also, `parse_datetime_or_default` has been written to be too generic. Think: it attempts to convert *any* value in JSON to a datetime, regardless of whether that's appropriate. You have a fixed dictionary format; adhere to it.

`self.created_on.__name__` is not necessary. You know the key name, so just... write it as a string.

Write unit tests.

`check` is a deceptive name. It doesn't check anything; it creates the file.

Don't `lru_cache`; just `cache`.

### Suggested

```
import json
from functools import cache
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from time import sleep
from typing import Any


def json_default(o: Any) -> Any:
    if isinstance(o, (date, datetime)):
        return o.isoformat()


def json_object_hook(d: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
    return {
        **d,
        'created_on': datetime.fromisoformat(d['created_on']),
    }


class Tick:
    def __init__(self, file_name: Path, lifetime: timedelta) -> None:
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.lifetime = lifetime

    def create(self) -> None:
        self.file_name.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        data = {'created_on': datetime.now()}
        with self.file_name.open('w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, default=json_default)
        self.get_created_on.cache_clear()

    @property
    def is_created(self) -> bool:
        return self.file_name.is_file()

    @cache  # avoid reading the file more than once until updated
    def get_created_on(self) -> datetime:
        with self.file_name.open() as f:
            return json.load(f, object_hook=json_object_hook)['created_on']

    @property
    def elapsed(self) -> timedelta:
        return datetime.now() - self.get_created_on()

    @property
    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        return self.is_created and self.elapsed < self.lifetime

    @property
    def is_expired(self) -> bool:
        return not self.is_valid


def test() -> None:
    lifetime = timedelta(seconds=1)
    tick = Tick(Path('noexist'), lifetime)
    assert not tick.is_created
    assert not tick.is_valid
    assert tick.is_expired

    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='_token_test.json') as temp:
        tick = Tick(Path(temp.name), lifetime)
        assert tick.is_created

        tick.create()
        assert tick.is_created
        assert tick.is_valid
        assert not tick.is_expired

        sleep(1.5)
        assert tick.is_created
        assert not tick.is_valid
        assert tick.is_expired


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Damn! This is clean as a whistle now; especially with the `timedelta`! I also love the new test code that I need practice more writing like that.

Answer (score 0):

This self-answer might not entirely be on-topic, but I think it's worth mentioning that `NamedTemporaryFile` won't work on Windows as it keeps the file open while the `Tick` class will try to open it again and fail. Only Linux can handle this.

In order to make the suggusted test work on Windows too, I wrote a similar class that releases the file after creation and provides its name:

````py
class TemporaryFileName:
    def __init__(self, suffix: str, create=False, delete=True):
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.create = create
        self.delete = delete

    def __enter__(self) -> Path:
        self._temp_name = Path(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), f"{os.urandom(4).hex()}_{self.suffix}"))
        try:
            return self._temp_name
        finally:
            if self.create:
                self._temp_name.open("x").close()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.delete and self._temp_name.is_file():
            os.remove(self._temp_name)
```
````